# osiset/laravel-shopify - Call to a member function getDomain() on null

Tags: laravel, shopify

when I tried to run the application on 127.0.0.1:8000/authenticate it gives me error
[image]

Comment: That looks like there's no signed in user when that code runs

Answer (score 0):

MIght be an issue for migration file.
refer this : https://github.com/osiset/laravel-shopify/issues/912

Answer (score 0):

It comes usually when you are trying to directly access the root URL. From Version 17 you can't access the root URL directly.
You need to access through admin/apps via Shopify.